# Checking Array for duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

Does this method check and replace randoms in the array?

```
public void generateNumbers()
   {

       for(int counter=0; counter< 6; counter++){

           numbers[counter]= 1+ (int)(Math.random()*49);
           for(int y = counter - 1; y >=0 ; y--){
               if(numbers[counter] == numbers[y]){
                   numbers[counter]= 1+ (int)(Math.random()*49);
                }
           }


    }
```

If there is duplicates I need to replace this with another random number and then check again. I want to check this using a loop if possible and not using collections.

The range of the numbers created by random should be 1 - 49.

Comment: why do you want to do it in a loop? What about the method contains() ? [documentation link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: why don't you use a set and check the size of this set after each add until you reach to the number of random number you want .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "rewind" back to `counter-1` on finding the duplicate, so that you start searching for duplicates again:

```
public void generateNumbers()
{

   for(int counter=0; counter< 6; counter++){

       numbers[counter]= 1+ (int)(Math.random()*49);
       for(int y = counter - 1; y >=0 ; y--){
           if(numbers[counter] == numbers[y]){
               numbers[counter]= 1+ (int)(Math.random()*49);
               y = counter - 1; // <<<===== ADDED
            }
       }


}
```

Your original method would fail if you start with this array

```
1 3 7 8
```

then generate 3, check it against 8 and 7, find duplicate 3, and generate 8 as a replacement. At this point, your algorithm would check 8 against 1, and be satisfied that there's no duplicate; this would be incorrect.

Comment: ok, but does this method work? Finding the duplicate and then if there is a duplicate in the array replacing it with a new random number?

Comment: @dancooper93 I just added an example to show you how it could break.

Comment: ok, i have seen that.. does the method above that you have added your code into now check for and then if needed replace them with a new random number, then check again?

Comment: @dancooper93 Give it a try - it should.

Comment: I have tried this many times and haven't come across a duplicate yet, I am just wondering if anyone can see if there is potential there for a duplicate to appear.

Comment: @dancooper93 I do not see how it would be possible to get duplicates in the list after adding a reset of the counter to `y = counter - 1`.

Comment: I was thinking the same from what I can tell by the logic and you also think that, hopefully this will work! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For such problems there are often better algorithms. Your example is modelling a lottery, which can be described as: *draw n elements out of a bucket of m elements*. In your case, n := 6; m := the numbers from 1 to 49 -- but you can adjust it as needed (and even have multiple elements in the buckets that are similar).

So, a better approach to this problem would be:

1. Create a base list containing all items you have available before drawing, i.e. a list containing the numbers 1..49
2. Create an empty result list
3. in a loop iterating n times, do the following:

   1. choose a random index of your list between 0 and the maximum number of items (still present in the list)
   2. Take the item at the index from 3.1 from your base list and add it to your result
   3. Remove the item at the index from the base list. This ensures that the same number won't appear a second time in your result. Consequently, the maximum number of items in your base list will be 1 smaller the next time you execute step 3.1

I won't go into detail on how to program said algorithm in Java, as its smelling a lot like homework.